# question mark against each row under label in Rapidminer

Tags: rapidminer

i have called an attribute as label in Rapid miner but when I run it I see a question mark against some of the rows. why?

Regards
Joseph

Comment: You need to provide some content to supplement this question.

Comment: Subject to providing more content, it looks like some of the labels are missing - this is what the `?` means.